# TypeError for a non-numerical vector, and to do the curl

Tags: python, vector, sympy

So I'm trying to solve a problem for a class, and I'm trying to do the curl, but it's in variables. I end up getting a TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so if anyone can make this work, I'd be really appreciative. Also, how would you make an array of [partial x, partial y, partial z]?

I set the symbols so that there wouldn't be an error with that and I'm using sympy.

```
import sympy 
import math 
from sympy import Symbol, diff, Matrix, sin, cos

alpha = Symbol('a')
B0 = Symbol('B0')
x = Symbol('x')
print ('Symbols: ', alpha, B0, x)

A = Matrix[0, (B0)*sin(alpha*x), (B0)*cos(alpha*x)]
print ('Matrix: ', A)
```

I expect a curl of (alpha)(0, B0sin(alpha*x), B0cos(alpha*x). It's pretty much a proof.

Comment: Try adding () around the Matrix arguments. `A = Matrix( [...] )` As it is right you, you are trying to subscript into the Matrix class which is why you're getting the 'type' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: It's not obvious from the `Matrix` documentation, but when you provide 3 arguments, it interprets them as `(number_of_row, number_of_columns, flat_list_of_values)`.  Normally though it expects a `list of row vectors`, e.g. `Matrix([[1,2,3]])` or `Matrix([[1],[2],[3]])` or `Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])`.

Comment: Ok adding the parenthesis worked! Thanks!